# Using a potentiometer to shift between negative outputs from either -2V and 2V

Tags: resistors, potentiometer

The question that I am wanting to ask is that I start off with either 5V or -5V which is reduced to -2V or 2V for my output for the potentiometer. My potentiometer has a 5k resistance and I am trying to find out how I can reduce my voltage with a resistor before it hits the potentiometer. I am needing help with understanding a simple way to find my resister. Step by step really helps me.

[image]

Comment: 1. Ignore RL as it's super high, assume no current in the white part of the circuit.
2. You know the voltage drop needed across A to B (4V) and the resistance in between them. So use V=IR to calculate the current (I) from V (4V) and R (5k). This current will flow all the way through each part of the yellow circuit.
3. You know how much voltage you need to drop in each of the R (5-2=3V) and from part 2 you know the current in the yellow cicruit, so use V=IR again knowing V&I to get R.

Comment: @DanSheppard , thank you! I have finished it and I finally understood a little bit more

Comment: A good way at solving all the problems like this is to hunt down places where you know two out of the three of V, I, R and calculate the other one. Currents into and out of a set of connected wires need to add up to zero (once you take into account the signs of "going in" and "coming out") so you can play "where does all that current go", and the voltage of connected wires will always be equal. This will often give you another place where you know two things, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You have a 5k potentiometer, and you want 4V across it from end to end.  That means that 0.8mA should be flowing through it (V/R = I).

Your total supply is 10V, and you need to lose 6V of that across the two resistors R.  In other words, you want 3V across each of the resistors, at a current of 0.8mA.  Using R = V/I, that gives 3750 ohms for each of the resistors.